# jQuery: change div text depending on changing variable value

Tags: jquery, html

I need to create a donations page for a website. Basically I want the user to use a slider bar to select the amount they wish to donate. I have used the following tutorial to create a basic slider bar - http://designm.ag/tutorials/howto-build-range-slider-input-with-jqueryui/.

```
<div id="defaultval">
    Slider Value: <span id="currentval">0</span>
</div>
<div id="defaultslide"></div>
```

The above code is taken from the tutorial and displays the slider bar. The value in the span tag 'currentval' changes as the user changes the place of the slider, as seen in the live demo of the tutorial http://designm.ag/previews/jqueryui-range-sliders/

The jQuery used for the slider bar is as follows:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#defaultslide').slider({ 
    max: 250,
    min: 0,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(e,ui) {
      $('#currentval').html(ui.value);
    }
  });
</script>
```

I then have a div below where I wish to display text describing a different perk depending on the value of the slider bar. E.g. if the slider bar value > 100 display perk 1, slider bar value > 200 display perk 2 etc...

```
<div id="perk">
   <span>"Perk number..."</span>
</div>
```

I've had a play around trying to do this but I've had no luck, the only way I can think of doing it is as follows:

```
if($value > 100) {
    $('#perk span').text('Perk number 1');
}
```

Obviously this is incorrect. How would I do this using jQuery?

Comment: what `$value` outputs? try alerting value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the value in the variable `$value` contains is not clear from the code you provided.

You should be attempting to find the `val()` or `.value` from the slider itself.

**Edit:** I found the solution! From looking at the source code of the tutorial, I found that the value of the slider is stored in a variable called `ui.value` within the scope of `slide: function(e,ui)`. Simply call that, as in:

```
if(ui.value > 100) {
    $('#perk span').text('Perk number 1');
}
```

do it within the slide function, like as follows:

```
  $('#defaultslide').slider({ 
    max: 1000,
    min: 0,
    value: 500,
    slide: function(e,ui) {
      if(ui.value > 100) {
       $('#perk span').text('Perk number 1');
     };
    }
  });
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: As I did not create the slider myself I'm not sure how to obtain the value. I was hoping someone more experienced would be able to help me do this @seanlevan

Comment: Sure, I edited the answer to reflect that. :) I hope that helped, and feel free to mark it as the correct answer with the checkmark next to it if it did. :)

Comment: No problem dude, anytime. :) Tell me if you have another question. @JoeMorgan

Comment: Just a quick one. Have you any idea how I can change the colour of the slider... So the bar before the current value is red and the bar after the current value stays grey? If that makes sense... @seanlevan

Comment: Ask another question. :) @JoeMorgan StackExchange has a limit of how many things you can answer in one.

Comment: Post another question. @JoeMorgan I'd be happy to help! :)